# how to calculate difference between these two times in excel

Tags: excel

`2016-10-31T15:26:39.569Z` AND `2016-10-31T03:00:00.462Z`

I am not able to find any functions for this calculations as these times are in UTC format. Is there any formula to convert them to normal time?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you searched for? There's [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903872/convert-utc-time-to-local), and many others when [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=Excel+UTC+time+to+local). Please also see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You need to replace `T` with a blank and remove the `Z`. Then, you can subtract the two values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing an ISO8601 date/time (including TimeZone) in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896116/parsing-an-iso8601-date-time-including-timezone-in-excel)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned only formulas not VBA - there has been a solution for this but it doesn't factor in the timezones which may be problematic for you.

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8))
```

If the timezones don't matter then this should help, if they do then there are VBA solutions further down on the link you could explore.

[Parsing an ISO8601 date/time (including TimeZone) in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896116/parsing-an-iso8601-date-time-including-timezone-in-excel)