# How to convert UTC Date to Datetime in VBA?

Tags: vba

I have a VBA-Macro Windows Form application.

I need to retrieve a datetime from an API which is retrieved as UTC date like (2022-03-28T22:34:48Z).

I'm trying to get the value like this:

```vb
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
For Each obj In Parsed("rows")
    with Support 
        .SupportEndDate = obj("supportenddate")
    End With
Next obj

ErrorHandler:
Err.Clear
Resume Next
```

The debugger is moving to `ErrorHandler` and the value doesn't set. I also tried to add `CDate` function before `obj("supportenddate")`.

Note: `.SupportEndDate` is a Date type. I added a watch to see the value of `obj("supportenddate")`. I found that it's a variant/string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903872/convert-utc-time-to-local

Answer (score 1):

This will attempt to convert it to a date from a string, but it will work only when it's in that `T/Z` format:

```
Function UTC2Date(s As String) As Variant
    ' example argument
    ' "2022-03-28T22:34:48Z"
    
    If InStr(s, "T") > 0 And InStr(s, "Z") > 0 Then
        UTC2Date = CDate(Split(s, "T")(0) & " " & Replace(Split(s, "T")(1), "Z", ""))
    Else
        UTC2Date = "ERROR"
    End If
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works on both Windows and Mac and does not use any APIs:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TIME_OFFSET
    offsetSign As Integer
    localOffsetPart As String
End Type
Private Type TIME_PART
    sValue As String
    hasFractionalPart As Boolean
    secsFractionalPart As String
    hasOffset As Boolean
    timeOffset As TIME_OFFSET
End Type
Private Type ISO_PARTS
    datePart As String
    hasTime As Boolean
    timePart As TIME_PART
End Type

'Expecting:
'   - Complete Date:
'       YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
'   - Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
'       YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
'   - Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds with a fractional part
'       YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
'where:
'   YYYY = four-digit year
'   MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
'   DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
'   hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
'   mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
'   ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
'   s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
'   TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
'       Z - UTC designator
'       "+" or "-" - local time zone offset (in hours and minutes)
Public Function ISOToUTC(ByVal isoDateTime As String) As Date
    Const methodName As String = "ISOToUTC"
    '
    If LenB(isoDateTime) = 0 Then Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Empty ISO string"
    '
    Dim regEx As Object: Set regEx = GetRegEx()
    Dim isoParts As ISO_PARTS
    '
    On Error Resume Next
    If regEx Is Nothing Then
        isoParts = ISOLike(isoDateTime)
    Else
        isoParts = ISORegEx(regEx, isoDateTime)
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Dim errDesc As String: errDesc = Err.Description
        On Error GoTo 0
        Err.Raise 5, methodName, errDesc
    End If
    '
    'Date and/or time could be invalid even if the pattern returned a result
    'Ex. Date 2017-12-41 or Time 25:14:78
    '
    Dim dt As Date
    '
    dt = CDate(isoParts.datePart)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid ISO string. Invalid date digits"
    End If
    If isoParts.hasTime Then
        With isoParts.timePart
            dt = dt + CDate(.sValue)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid ISO string. Invalid time digits"
            End If
            If .hasFractionalPart Then
                Const secondsPerDay As Long = 24& * 60& * 60&
                dt = dt + CDbl(.secsFractionalPart) / secondsPerDay
            End If
            If .hasOffset Then
                dt = dt + .timeOffset.offsetSign * CDate(.timeOffset.localOffsetPart)
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid ISO string. Invalid timezone offset"
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    '
    ISOToUTC = dt
End Function

'https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html
Private Function GetRegEx() As Object
    On Error Resume Next 'Use Late Binding to get the available RegExp library
    Set GetRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function ISORegEx(ByVal regEx As Object _
                        , ByVal isoDateTime As String) As ISO_PARTS
    Const pDesignatorSign As String = "(\+|-)"
    Const pLocalDesignator As String = "(" & pDesignatorSign & "\d{2}:\d{2})"
    Const pZoneDesignator As String = "(Z|" & pLocalDesignator & ")"
    Const pDecimal As String = "(.{1}\d+)?"
    Const pTime As String = "(T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}" & pDecimal & pZoneDesignator & ")?"
    Const pDate As String = "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"
    Const pISO As String = "^" & pDate & pTime & "$"
    Dim subGroups As Object
    '
    With regEx
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = pISO
        With .Execute(isoDateTime)
            If .Count = 0 Then Err.Raise 5, , "Invalid ISO string"
            Set subGroups = .Item(0).SubMatches
        End With
    End With
    With ISORegEx
        .datePart = Left$(isoDateTime, 10)
        .hasTime = Not IsEmpty(subGroups.Item(0))
        If Not .hasTime Then Exit Function
    End With
    With ISORegEx.timePart
        .sValue = Replace(subGroups.Item(0), "T", vbNullString)
        .hasFractionalPart = Not IsEmpty(subGroups.Item(1))
        If .hasFractionalPart Then
            .secsFractionalPart = subGroups.Item(1)
            .sValue = Replace(.sValue, .secsFractionalPart, vbNullString)
        End If
        'Remove the time zone designator (Z or offset) from the time part
        .sValue = Replace(.sValue, subGroups.Item(2), vbNullString)
        .hasOffset = Not IsEmpty(subGroups.Item(4))
        If Not .hasOffset Then Exit Function
    End With
    With ISORegEx.timePart.timeOffset
        Dim offsetSign As String: offsetSign = subGroups.Item(4)
        .localOffsetPart = Replace(subGroups.Item(3), offsetSign, vbNullString)
        .offsetSign = IIf(offsetSign = "+", 1, -1)
    End With
End Function

Private Function ISOLike(ByVal isoDateTime As String) As ISO_PARTS
        Dim dateTimeParts() As String
        '
        dateTimeParts = Split(isoDateTime, "T")
        Select Case UBound(dateTimeParts, 1) - LBound(dateTimeParts, 1) + 1
        Case 1
            ISOLike.hasTime = False
        Case 2
            ISOLike.hasTime = True
            ISOLike.timePart.sValue = dateTimeParts(UBound(dateTimeParts, 1))
        Case Else
            Err.Raise 5, , "Invalid ISO string. Multiple 'T' separators"
        End Select
        ISOLike.datePart = dateTimeParts(LBound(dateTimeParts, 1))
        '
        If Not ISOLike.datePart Like "####-##-##" Then
            Err.Raise 5, , "Invalid ISO string. Invalid Date part"
        End If
        If Not ISOLike.hasTime Then Exit Function
        If Not ISOLike.timePart.sValue Like "##:##:##[.,Z,+,-]*" Then
            Err.Raise 5, , "Invalid ISO string. Invalid Time part"
        End If
        '
        With ISOLike.timePart
            If Mid$(.sValue, 9, 1) = "." Then 'Remove fractional part first
                .hasFractionalPart = True
                If Not .sValue Like "##:##:##.#*[Z,+,-]*" Then
                    Err.Raise 5, , "Invalid ISO string. Invalid Time Fractional part"
                End If
                '
                Dim fractEnd As Long: fractEnd = InStr(10, .sValue, "Z")
                If fractEnd = 0 Then fractEnd = InStr(10, .sValue, "+")
                If fractEnd = 0 Then fractEnd = InStr(10, .sValue, "-")
                '
                .secsFractionalPart = Mid$(.sValue, 9, fractEnd - 9)
                '
                Dim fracPattern As String
                fracPattern = "." & String$(Len(.secsFractionalPart) - 1, "#")
                '
                If Not .secsFractionalPart Like fracPattern Then
                    Err.Raise 5, , "Invalid ISO string. Invalid Time Fractional part"
                End If
                '
                'Replace first occurence only to avoid cases like: 12:12:12.451Z.451
                .sValue = Replace(.sValue, .secsFractionalPart, vbNullString, 1, 1)
            End If
            '
            Select Case Mid$(.sValue, 9, 1)
            Case "Z"
                .hasOffset = False
                If Len(.sValue) > 9 Then
                    Err.Raise 5, , "Invalid ISO string. Extra characters after 'Z'"
                End If
            Case "+"
                .hasOffset = True
                .timeOffset.offsetSign = 1
            Case "-"
                .hasOffset = True
                .timeOffset.offsetSign = -1
            End Select
            '
            If .hasOffset Then
                If Not .sValue Like "##:##:##[+,-]##:##" Then
                    Err.Raise 5, , "Invalid ISO string. Invalid timezone offset"
                Else
                    .timeOffset.localOffsetPart = Right$(.sValue, 5)
                End If
            End If
            .sValue = Left$(.sValue, 8)
        End With
End Function
```

Here is a quick test:

```
Sub TestISOToUTC()
    Debug.Assert ISOToUTC("2022-03-28") = DateSerial(2022, 3, 28)
    Debug.Assert ISOToUTC("2022-03-28T22:34:48Z") = DateSerial(2022, 3, 28) + TimeSerial(22, 34, 48)
    Debug.Assert ISOToUTC("2022-03-28T22:34:48+01:00") = DateSerial(2022, 3, 28) + TimeSerial(23, 34, 48)
    Debug.Assert ISOToUTC("2022-03-28T22:34:48-01:00") = DateSerial(2022, 3, 28) + TimeSerial(21, 34, 48)
    Debug.Assert ISOToUTC("2022-03-28T22:34:48.45+01:00") = DateSerial(2022, 3, 28) + TimeSerial(23, 34, 48) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) * 0.45
End Sub
```

The regEx solution is more compact but the `Like` solution is around 300 times faster. So, you could remove the regEx logic if you wish and it will still work on both Win and Mac.